# Refreshing JTable removes Titles

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I have a JTable that I populate through a for each loop. when I click the Refresh button I want the table to be refreshed which it then runs through the for each loop and repopulates the JTable, this works great except for the fact that when I refresh the table it grays out my titles. Here is the code for everything. Also I am getting a casting exception thrown when using the HeaderRenderer because I can cast it to a DefaultTableCellModel yet the reason I have that class is to get my titles to center which works anyway. So here is the code for the classes I am having trouble with.

HeaderRenderer Class:

```
    package privatelessontrackernetbeans;

    import java.awt.Component;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
    import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

    /**
     *
     * @author trashgod
     * @author Brent Coleman
     */
    public class HeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer;

        public HeaderRenderer(JTable table) {
            try {
                renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getTableHeader()
                        .getDefaultRenderer();
                renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                System.out.println("Cannot be cast to DefaultTableCellRender. " +
                        "I still dont know why.");
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println("Null Pointer because of the other exception.");
            }
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param col
         * @return 
         */
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (
            JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                    int row, int col) {

            try {
                return renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Class with the JTable in it (Just the method with the problem)

```
    private void postInitComponents() {
        //Table for students that need more lessons
        DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        dtm.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
        //Center the cells
        DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, centerRenderer);
        //Center the Titles
        JTableHeader header = jTable1.getTableHeader();
        header.setDefaultRenderer(new HeaderRenderer(jTable1));
        studentsNeedToPay = checkStudentsLessons();
        for (Instructor key : studentsNeedToPay.keySet()) {
            ArrayList<Student> values = studentsNeedToPay.get(key);
            boolean listed = false;
            for (Student s : values) {
                //Instructor already listed
                if (listed) {
                    Object[] data = {null, s.getName(),
                            s.getLessonsRemaining()};
                    dtm.addRow(data);
                } else {//Instructor not listed
                    Object[] data = {key.getName(), s.getName(), 
                            s.getLessonsRemaining()};
                    dtm.addRow(data);
                    listed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem with your header is caused by the class cast exception you're getting. The thing is the table header's renderer cannot be casted as `DefaultTableCellRenderer` in your code because you're setting a new `HeaderRenderer` object as default renderer here:

```
 JTableHeader header = jTable1.getTableHeader();
 header.setDefaultRenderer(new HeaderRenderer(jTable1));
```

Since this class doesn't extend from `DefaultTableCellRenderer` then you'll get a class cast exception at this line:

```
public HeaderRenderer(JTable table) {
    try {
        renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        ...        
    } catch (ClassCastException e) { ... }
}
```

In any case if your goal is just get the heder's text centered you don't even need to provide a new table cell renderer. This should be enough:

```
private void postInitComponents() {
    ...
    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) jTable1.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
    renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    ...
}
```

---

#### Off-topic

About this:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
dtm.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
```

This way you're accesing the underlying data structure (implemented as `Vector`) directly which is wrong. You can achieve the same by setting the row's count to `0`:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
dtm.setRowCount(0);
```

Comment: you might consider going a step further in the off-topic: it's *plain wrong* to access the underlying datastructure :-)

Comment: @BrentColeman you're welcome! And no, I'm not. I'm just a guy who has dealt with Java and Swing for 4 years and is still learning :P